# PrestaShop Images

Tags: image, png, prestashop

I have Prestashop 1.4.9.0 installed with my PHP project. When I add a new product, I upload an image in PNG format, but when it is shown on the client side, the image is in JPG format.

How can you keep the image extension?

Answer (score 7):

At Back Office  > Preferences > Images you have 3 options for "Image quality":

- Use JPEG
- Use PNG only if the base image is in PNG format
- Use PNG for all images

By default all the images are in JPEG (PNG are converted), so you can either choose to use the 2nd option (to not convert images) or the 3rd option - to convert the JPEG images to PNG.

Comment: I tried all three of them. But even then the uploaded png image is converted to jpg

Comment: The image is not converted to JPEG, it just has .jpg extension. If you open the images in some text editor, you will see that it starts with: ‰PNG

Comment: can we change the image extension to png??

Comment: Yes, you can - if you edit all the .php, .tpl & .js files that use that extension, replacing it with .png, reupload all your images and hope that everything goes well. 

If you ask me, this is highly unadvisable and can bring you ONLY negatives. I can't see a single advantage from that.

Comment: thank you, but is there any way to change product images only which produce png files for png uploads only?

Comment: No, there's no way to do that.

Comment: can you tell me there is a way to save texture image in product attribute with different size from editing the core files..

Comment: The more I use PrestaShop, the less I like it.

Comment: @Vivek yes, you can do it by overriding two classes Image and, ImageManager but is is never recommended to override core code until it is inevitable.

Answer (score 2):

If you have try first answer (At Back Office > Preferences > Images you have 3 options for "Image quality":) it mast work, but you will see image extension .jpg. But if you will look to image code it will be png. If you need different extensions you need to change core and .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the image pref in the CMS it should work. The images will still show as jpg but will keep the transparency properties of a png.