# Prestashop stores png images with jpg extensions

Tags: image, image-processing, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In PrestaShop 1.6 I've set to use PNG for all images,
when I upload transparent PNG image to product, it works properly, but PS stores it with .jpg extension - the file really IS png, only the extension is wrong - does anybody know how to fix that?

Feel free to ask any additional questions if it would help or would clear things up a bit more.

Thanks.

Comment: Dirrection on where to change it might be in answer comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279192/prestashop-images

Answer (score 0):

You can force parameter in png -> Image -> Image Generation Options -> Use PNG for all images.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you force parameter in png -> Image->Image Generation Optins -> Use PNG for all images, **Prestashop 1.6 will generate all images with "jpg"** estension, but if **you change the extension** ("jpg" to "png"), you will see: **it's a png file**.

Comment: I basicaly already said that in my question x) I still consider it a bug, and I am still looking for a way how to fix it :)